# Number of triangles in a Graph/Network

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Given An undirected graph/Network, and its adjacency matrix **A**, and **1** (A column vector with all elements as 1).

How do we represent the problem of finding the number of triangles in the network (3-cliques) in terms of **A**, and **1**.

I do understand to find the triangle A summation of $A_{ij}*A_{jk}*A_{ik}$,where $i,j,k$ are vertices, but how do we represent in terms of **A**, and **1**

Answer (score 4):

The summation $A_{ij} A_{jk} A_{ki}$ can be written $\text{trace}(A^3)$. Don't forget to divide by 6.

Answer (score 0):

$|\{(x,y,z) : x \ne y, x\ne z, z\ne y, A[x][y]=A[x][z]=A[z][y]=1\}|$.

Comment: ...divided by 6.  But this seems equivalent to the OP's candidate answer that was excluded since it didn't fit the description "in terms of $A$ and $\mathbf{1}$".